# Proper way to process the huge amount of data from a sensor using Parallel.For

Tags: c#

I am getting the huge amount of data from a sensor. In order to speed up data processing, I thought of using [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx). Below is the sample code:

```
object sync = new object();
private Random random = new Random();
private List<byte> container = new List<byte>();
private readonly int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;
private readonly int DATA_LENGTH = 217088;
private readonly int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;

private void getPointsFromSensor(out Point2D[] points2d, out Point3D[] points3d)
{
    points2d = new Point2D[DATA_LENGTH];
    points3d = new Point3D[DATA_LENGTH];
    for (var index = 0; index < DATA_LENGTH; index++)
    {
        points2d[index] = new Point2D(random.Next(-index, index), random.Next(-index, index));
        points3d[index] = new Point3D(random.NextDouble(), random.NextDouble(), random.NextDouble());
    }
}

private void OnDataArrived(object sendor, DataArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    getPointsFromSensor(out Point2D[] points2d, out Point3D[] points3d);

    int validDataCount = 0;

    container.Clear(); // Remove old points
    // reserving 4 bytes for storing 'validDataCount' and we are going to modify it later
    container.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(validDataCount));

    Parallel.For(0, DATA_LENGTH, index =>
    {
        int points2dX = points2d[index].X;
        int points2dY = points2d[index].Y;

        if (points2dX >= 0 && points2dX < FRAME_WIDTH && points2dY >= 0 && points2dY < FRAME_HEIGHT)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                container.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(points3d[index].X));
                container.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(points3d[index].Y));
                container.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(points3d[index].Z));
            }
            Interlocked.Increment(ref validDataCount);
        }
    });

    var validDataCountBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(validDataCount);//4 bytes
    container[0] = validDataCountBytes[0]; container[1] = validDataCountBytes[1];
    container[2] = validDataCountBytes[2]; container[3] = validDataCountBytes[3];
}
```

The `Point2D` and `Point3D` are defined as follows:

```
class Point2D
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Point2D(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

class Point3D
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

It turns out that the `Parallel.For` version is taking much time compared to simple `for` loop.

**I am wondering if there exists is a better way to use `Parallel.For` inside a callback function in C#.**

Comment: You should post your **real** code otherwise we can't really help you. Take the code directly from your IDE and paste it into your question. `// Random values just in this code snippet` just makes your question bordering off topic.

Comment: I have now voted to close because of example code. Two comments from you that this isn't your **real actual code** is reason enough.

Comment: Now you aren't allowed anymore because you already received answer. See: *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 5):

Usually it makes absolutely no sense to use a parallel loop with a `lock` inside it. The performance loss you are talking about comes most probably from it. They cannot run in parallel because they have to wait for each other. The `lock` also costs some time and if it happens to often, the parallel loop might actually be slower then the normal one.

You might gain some performance if you redesign it in a way that does not requrie synchronization.

Answer (score 5):

There are three rules I find useful when working with parallel loops:

1. Do not lock inside the loop. (already explained in t3chb0t's answer)
2. Do not write to a shared buffer inside a loop, unless you can do it in a thread-safe manner *without any additional synchronization* (including concurrent collections or other objects that use locks internally). In case you can't, use [one of the overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx) that supports local states, and write to that local state without a lock.
3. Do not iterate over every element of array unless a significant amount of work is required to process each element. In general, you should split your initial data into reasonably-sized chunks (using `ArraySegment` class, for example), and use `Parallel.For` to iterate over array of those chunks.

Following those three rules should give you satisfactory results.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. I need to collect the bytes, hence I used list. However since it is not thread safe, I used a lock. I also tried using `ConcurrentBag` but didn't see any performance improvements. Any suggestions?

Comment: Concurrent collections have internal synchronization. This does count as *additional synchronization* that I mentioned in (2), so they are a no-go. In your code you always get 8 bytes per iteration. So you can simply create a `byte[DATA_LENGTH*8]` array and write directly into it using indexes without locks. Calculate write indexes as `index*8`, so they do not overlap.

Comment: I see. I got your point but there is one problem. Some of the elements of the array `byte[DATA_LENGTH * 8] ` may be empty, since some `index` can generate invalid value and hence the conditional statement `if` is going to return `false`.

Comment: Another idea is to create a separate results collection per chunk, which can then be combined into the final results when all chunks have been processed.

Comment: Yes, Pieter is right. If empty spaces in resulting array are unacceptable, you have to fill local buffers instead. See the documentation to overloaded `Parallel.For` method that I linked in my answer.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet and Nikita B: Thank you very much. I am thinking about it. Meanwhile, I have another finding of the c# code posted in the question.  Removing `lock (sync)` from the code is throwing `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Please note that the above sample code is a console application. In the real Windows Form application `container.AddRange(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 })` is throwing following error `ArgumentException: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.`. Don't forget that `container` is `List<byte> container`.

Comment: Updated the code in question for better understanding. Please have a look. Apologies for the inconvenience. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, it's worth noting that you're doing very *little* work inside the parallel.for - grabbing two random values, performing a few comparison, getting some bytes and performing some add-range and additions.

These are very fast, very cheap operations.  Parallel.For adds in a ton of overhead that likely exceeds the cost of the operations.

*Then* its worth noting, as other answers have, that you have locked some of the slower operations - meaning that it'll run that part at no faster than single thread speed.  Having a lock inside a parallel operation isn't necessarily bad (e.g. if it's only a very small fraction of that operations work) but by definition it adds a bottleneck.

When working on small, higher performance loops like this I try to do the following:

1)  Have each thread work on its own data, and synchronize at the end (or in a thread-safe, high-speed manner like interlocked)
2)  Batch the data into appropriately sized chunks before passing to the thread.

For example:

```
var threadCount = Enviroment.ProcessorCount;
var threadContainers = new Enumerable.Range(0,threadCount).Select(_ => new List<byte>()).ToArray();
Parallel.For(0, threadCount, thread=>
{ 
    //review, can easily be off by one due to division
    for (int index = 0; index<( DataLength/threadCount); index++)
    {
        // Random values just in this code snippet
        int config_1 = random.Next(-index, index); 
        int config_2 = random.Next(-index, index);

        if (config_1 >= 0 && config_1 < FRAME_WIDTH && config_2 >= 0 && config_2 < FRAME_HEIGHT)
        {
            //this *may* be threadsafe, but worth reviewing to be sure.
            threadContainers[thread].AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(config_1));
            threadContainers[thread].AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(config_2));
            Interlocked.Increment(ref validDataCount);
        }
    }
});
var container = containers.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList(); 
container.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(validDataCount));
```

Of course, this can get tedious,  So do consider other parallel tools and patterns to assist.  For example PLinq might be a good example in this case, because it can do the batching behind the scenes *and* help manage the creation and flow of state between the threads (whereas we had to do that manually here.

Comment: Amazing.  However, I am not able to understand it completely. Before asking my query, let me first explain the real scenario. The line `int config_1 = random.Next(-index, index)` is `int config_1 = sensor_data(index)` in the real code, where the length of `sensor_data` is `DataLength`. In order to get all `int config_1`, I iterate over complete `DataLength`. Hence `0 < index < DATA_LENGTH`. **Ques:** I see that in your suggestion `0 < index < (DATA_LENGTH/threadCount)`. So I suspect that instead of looking at complete data, it is looking only over `(DATA_LENGTH/threadCount)` portion of data.

Comment: Updated the code in question for better understanding. Please have a look. Apologies for the inconvenience. Thank you again.

Comment: The exact chunking logic is situation dependent - for example in the demo while the count of the loops was important, the order is next.  You may find in reality the order and position is important - leading to something like:  `for (int index = (length/threadcount)*thread; index<(length/threadcount)*(thread+1); index++)` (please doublecheck, esp on unusual values).   What I often do is write a Method that takes in array, and splits it into n chunks to make life simpler e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq

Comment: make sense. i will check the values and get back to you later. thank you very much.